# Comparing hotspots to points using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, hot-spot

I've done a simple hotspot analysis of car accidents to show where they are concentrated. I did this in ArcGIS, first using the Getis-Ord hotspot tool with an accident point shapefile. I then used Spatial Analyst to interpolate a raster surface from the GetisOrd to give me a nice heatmap across the city.

What I'd like to next is compare this heatmap with venues, things like liquor stores, schools, malls to see there is a link between them (I was even thinking of times, but that might be a bit to hard).

I have the points for these buildings, and I thought about doing a second hotspot analysis, but then I don't know how to combine this data together or if its even the right way to go about it.

Is there a way to combine the buildings and the accident points into one file and run that through hot-spot?

I've got access to ArcGIS and Spatial Analyst.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What GIS software are you using?  How precisely did you do your "simple hotspot analysis of car accidents to show where they are concentrated"?